# zf2 \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql using predicate in where condition

Tags: php, zend-db, zend-framework2

i really don't get the point how to use predicates in zend framework 2.

this is what i got:

```
$sql->select()
        ->columns(array('GroupedColum'
            ,'minValue' => new Expression('min(ValueColumn)')))
        ->from('ValueTable')
        ->group('GroupedColum')
        ->order('minValue')
        ->order('GroupedColum')
        ->limit(10);
```

this is working fine

now i want to apply somethin like that:

```
$predicate = new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Predicate();
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn','20);
```

this is what i tried, it throws no error, but it is not working :-(

This is what i expect as SQL:

```
select GroupedColum
    , min(ValueColumn) as minValue
from ValueTable
where filterColumn > 20
group by GroupedColum
order by minValue
    GroupedColum
limit 10;
```

Comment: you should add your solution as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved the problem by viewing the source code of `zf2`

If you know how to do it, it is really easy, the code above was almost right!

Instead of

```
$predicate = new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Predicate();
```

you have to use

```
$predicate = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
```

it is an empty derived class, that is used in Zend\Db\Sql\Sql

**this is the complete working example:**

```
$sql->select()
    ->columns(array('GroupedColum'
        ,'minValue' => new Expression('min(ValueColumn)')))
    ->from('ValueTable')
    ->group('GroupedColum')
    ->order('minValue')
    ->order('GroupedColum')
    ->limit(10);
$predicate = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn','20'));
```

Answer (score 6):

A bit late but you can also accomplish this by doing

```
$sql->select()
->columns(array('GroupedColum'
    ,'minValue' => new Expression('min(ValueColumn)')))
->from('ValueTable')
->group('GroupedColum')
->order('minValue')
->order('GroupedColum')
->limit(10)
->where
    ->greaterThan('filterColumn', '20');
```

The __get magic method of \Zend\Db\Sql\Select has a case for where which returns the current where() predicate, which allows you to do more complex things such as

```
$sql->where
    ->greaterThan('filterColumn', '20')
    ->or
    ->greaterThan('filterColumn', '30');
```

vs

```
$predicate = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn', '20'));
$sql->where($predicate->greaterThan('filterColumn', '30'), 'OR');
```

For a list of all predicates available in ZF 2 (2.1.0) from the Where predicate see:

- https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/blob/release-2.1.0/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Predicate/Predicate.php
- http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Predicate.Predicate.html

Comment: @Pang Update to referenced version, note that ZF2 has changed significantly since the time of this posting.